# Find the Cylindrical and cartesian equation of the above cone

Tags: calculus

Consider the following Cone :

[image]

**Find the Cylindrical and cartesian equation of the above cone.**

**Answer:**

**Cylindrical Co-ordinate system:**

$ x=r \cos \theta, \\ y=r \sin \theta, \\ z=z , \ \ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \ $

**Cartesian Co-ordinate system :**

$ r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2 } , \\ \theta=\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x} , \\ z=z \ $

**Am I right so far ?**

**Help me out**

Comment: You’ve written down conversion formulas between the two coordinate systems, not equations of the cone.

Comment: what would be the equations of the above cone ?

Answer (score 1):

In the cylindrical system $z = r$

Then substituting $r = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$

Gives $z = \sqrt {x^2+ y^2}$ in Cartesian.

Comment: what are the equations of the Cone in different coordinate systems ?